# C++ Function calling fails

Tags: c++

I get the following error when declaring a function:

```
Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example.cpp:23:5: error: no matching function for call to 'printstats'
    printstats(&x, y);
    ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example.cpp:10:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::string *' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > *') to 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') for 1st argument; remove &
void printstats(const std::string& x, int statnum);
     ^
/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example.cpp:12:6: note: candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'const std::string *' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> > *') to 'char *' for 1st argument
void printstats(char * x, int stat_num)
     ^
1 error generated.
[Finished in 0.9s with exit code 1]
[shell_cmd: g++ "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example.cpp" -o "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example" && "/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example"]
[dir: /Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++]
[path: /anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

The function takes two inputs and I am calling it from `main`.
I am expecting an output which has the following formatting `Strength: 7`.
Here is the code:

```
// C program to illustrate
// call by value
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream> 
#include <ctime>    // For time()
#include <cstdlib>  // For srand() and rand()
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

void printstats(const std::string& x, int statnum);

void printstats(char * x, int stat_num)
{
    printf("%s: %d", x, stat_num);
}

int main(void)
{
    const std::string&x = "Strength";
    int y = 7;

    // Passing parameters
    printstats(&x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay. Will edit in

Comment: @MaxBethke Don't worry about downvotes.

Comment: The signatures of `printstats`'s declaration and definition obviously differ. That's not allowed. `const std::string&x = "Strength";` also does not really make sense. Passing a pointer argument is redundant because C++ has references and the function only reads from the string anyway, so passing a `const std::string &` is way better here. Or a `std::string &&`. The `void` in `main(void)` is redundant in C++. So is `return 0;`. `printf` is the C way. C++ has `std::cout`. I suggest you get a good C++ book or learn C++ properly. Python and C++ are entirely different. Like apples and oranges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function prototype `void printstats(const std::string& x, int statnum)` and function definition `void printstats(char * x, int stat_num)` expect different parameters.

One expects a `const string &` as the first parameter and the other expects a `char *` as the first parameter.

Change both to have the same parameters and make sure your function call passes the appropriate argument(s) to the function.

Comment: I did what you said and got a different error: `/Users/masterprogrammer/PycharmProjects/WolvesBatsRocks/c++/c++example.cpp:14:22: error: cannot pass non-POD object of type 'const std::string' (aka 'const basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, allocator<char> >') to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'char *' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]
    printf("%s: %d", x, stat_num);
            ~~       ^`

Comment: I changed both to have const std::string& x, instead of char * x

Comment: Is it because you're now trying to `printf` a `std::string`?  Use `cout` instead.

Comment: Do I have to <include> cout? I'm getting undeclared identifier 'cout'

Comment: Pretty much with every C++ standard library thing you'll have to look up which particular header it's in; it's never super intuitive.  [std::cout](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout) is in `<iostream>`, apparently.

Comment: It needs to be pre-fixed with `std::`.  `std::cout << x << std::endl;` should work.  Consider changing everything to drop the reference to a string and just use a string instead.

Comment: @MaxBethke do not succumb to the temptation to ignore warnings. A warning is emitted when your program is syntactically correct but most likely logically flawed. Warnings are your first line of defense against simple mistakes.

Comment: @MaxBethke What is your warning?

Comment: I fixed the warning easily, It was telling me that I was making some strings wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define an address type, but instead you can pass addresses of other variables which I think neither is what you're aiming to do.

& in method signature means call by reference which basically means inside the function the reference is used to access the actual argument used in the call. 
To make it work, define a `string` and pass it directly.

```
std::string x= "Strength";
int y = 7;

printstats(x, y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You really need to read a good introductory C++ book. It seems that you took an example from a C book, and tried to use it in C++ without understanding of what's happening.

I removed the unnecessary includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

//Use a reference to string object instead of char pointer
void printstats(const std::string& x, int stat_num)
{
    //printf is a C function that expects a C char* straing,
    //so we need to convert the C++ string into it
    printf("%s: %d", x.c_str(), stat_num);
}

int main(void)
{
    //no need for "&" here - it's totally incorrect.
    //It is an operation of taking an address of a variable.
    const std::string x = "Strength";
    int y = 7;

    //no need for & here too
    printstats(x, y);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Strength: 7

Comment: Yes, I do realize I need to do more C++ learning. I didn't know how much C++ differs from python at first. I thought it was just & and * stuff.

Comment: The `extern` keyword is not needed to declare a function prototype.

Comment: @PaulBelanger Maybe I used a wrong term. I should probably say "function declaration", not prototype.

Comment: The `extern` is unnecessary, the function declaration is not a function call, the headers are still wrong. This is not a good answer.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb I said that extern is unnecessary "But you don't need it here as you function is defined before being called.". Did you read this?

Comment: `void printstats(const std::string& x, int statnum);` is not a function call. `extern` doesn't do what you say it does with respect to functions.

Comment: @MaxBethke *I didn't know how much C++ differs from python at first.* -- C++ is a language you really have to learn the "long way" by reading reputable books, going to reputable websites, etc..  It is not a language that fits on a "cheat sheet" or two, like some other languages.

Comment: @user4581301 Ahh yes, I overlooked "void" at the beginning. Removed the incorrect answer portion.

Comment: @StephenM.Webb The headers are correct. Disagree with you. I used `stdio.h` for `printf` and `iostream` for `std::string`. Maybe, we can use another header instead of `iostream`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Python can also be complicated if you use it for non-trivial tasks.

Comment: @user4035 Any language can be complicated.  However the OP's code is trivial and *still* an understanding of C++ is required.

Comment: A warning: iostream does not always contain an include of string. To reduce bloat and speed compile times some implementations only have a forward declaration of `std::string` to meet the requirements of some functions and methods that require a reference to `std::string`. You can get some really weird error messages if you count on iostream containing a full definition of `std::string`.

Comment: @user4581301 Yes I thought about that too. But what should we include to get the definition of std::string? Compiles well in Visual studio 2008 with iostream though.

Comment: `#include <string>`

Comment: @user4581301 Haha, just found it myself in Stroustrups book and wanted to tell you.